# Why do I see 301 redirect every time I visit `http://www.iqueen.my`?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm visiting a website whose URL is `http://www.iqueen.my`. This site returns a `301 redirect` that takes me to `https://www.iqueen.my/`.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) says

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
>   permanent URL redirection, meaning current links or records using the
>   URL that the response is received for should be updated. The new URL
>   should be provided in the Location field included with the response.
>   The 301 redirect is considered a best practice for upgrading users
>   from HTTP to HTTPS.

I guess that this means that the information of where to be redirected to  is cached inside the browser. So when I type `http://www.iqueen.my` in my chrome for the second time, chrome will take me to `https://www.iqueen.my/` directly without visiting `http://www.iqueen.my`.

But my guess is wrong.

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, every time when I visit `http://www.iqueen.my`, chrome still visits `http://www.iqueen.my` and get a 301 redirect.

Does chrome really visit `http://www.iqueen.my`?

Do I misunderstand the meaning of `Moved Permanently`?

Comment: _“I guess that this means that the information of where to be redirected to is cached inside the browser”_ - no, not necessarily. Moved Permanently first and foremost means that the requested content has moved somewhere else. Whether this redirect itself gets cached depends on other factors, such as the caching headers returned together with the redirect for the originally requested URL. (Plus, here Cloudflare is in the mix as well, so their browser/bot detection might play into things as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a column in chrome developer tools which say that the 301 redirect information is taken from the disk cache.

[image]

This means chrome still does a 301 redirect and the information of where to be redirected to is stored in the cache of chrome.